# Pasar Variable PHP A Ventana Modal

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Cordial Saludo.

Espero me puedan ayudar con lo que quiero hacer.

Tengo una tabla PHP - HTML

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno, el caso es que, cuando doy click en el lapiz, abré una ventana Modal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer, es pasar 1 variable a la ventana Modal, al hacer click en el lapiz.

Esta es la estructura del pedazo que necesito:

```
<td><?php echo $row['Descr']; ?><a href="#miModal" data-toggle="modal"><img src="img/editar.png" class="btn"></a></td>
```

y este es el Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="miModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Editar Nombre del Concepto</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label>Nombre Concepto:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required="on" autocomplete="off" class="form-control"><br/>
            <input type="button" name="insert" onclick="actualizarnombrecon();" class="btn btn-primary"  value="GUARDAR">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">CANCELAR</button>           
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Realmente no se como hacerlo funcionar

Espero me puedan ayudar

Gracias de Antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que estás usando algún framework, del estilo de Bootstrap. Normalmente estos frameworks permiten abrir la ventana modal automáticamente, como creo que estás haciendo, añadiendo los atributos `data-toggle="modal"` y `href="#miModal"`, o bien abrirla programáticamente, que es lo que necesitas.

Dependiendo del framework que estés usando, tendrás que hacer algo parecido a esto:

Cambiar el *botón* del lápiz (quitando el link `<a>`):

```
<img src="img/editar.png"
     class="lapiz"
     data-descr="<?php echo htmlentities($row['Descr']); ?>">
```

Añadir un código que te maneje el click en el lápiz, actualice el campo y muestre la ventana:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.lapiz', function () {

        var descr = $(this).attr('data-descr');
        $('#miModal input[name=nombre]').val(descr);

        // aquí es cuando tienes que mirar la documentación de tu framework
        $('#miModal').showModal(); // o similar

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Utilizo Boostrap

Comment: Ya Logré hacer lo que quería, gracias amigo